# What does "as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class" mean?

Tags: java, spring

[Documentation is here!](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired-qualifiers.html)

I can't understand the bold part of the following sentence, ...maybe entire sentence :(

> Trying to inject the results from @Bean methods on the same configuration class is effectively a self-reference scenario as well. **Either lazily resolve such references in the method signature where it is actually needed (as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class) or declare the affected @Bean methods as static, decoupling them from the containing configuration class instance and its lifecycle.** Otherwise, such beans are only considered in the fallback phase, with matching beans on other configuration classes selected as primary candidates instead (if available).

**To ensure that I understand this sentence correctly, let me first explain my understanding.**

Self-referencing refers to the situation where Bean A calls Bean B within the same configuration class, or when other Beans are used as parameters, right?

Like this.

```java
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    Course course() {
        Course course = new Course();

        return course;
    }

    @Bean
    Teacher teacher(Course course) {    // self-reference
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        Course course1 = course();      // self-reference
        System.out.println(course);
        teacher.setCourse(course);

        return teacher;
    }

    @Bean
    String[] courseList() {
        String[] cs = {"OS", "Network"};

        return cs;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Course {
    @Resource(name = "courseList")
    private String[] courseList;
}

public class Teacher {
    private Course course;
    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teacher{" +
                "course=" + course +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If my concept description above is correct, then I can proceed with the solution as described in the documentation.

1. declare the affected @Bean methods as static.

   I think this should be correct, `CGLIB` directly invoke `static Course course` method, rather than invoke `proxy object`.

```java
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    static Course course() {  // add static qualifier
        Course course = new Course();

        return course;
    }

    // ...
}
```

2. Either lazily resolve such references in the method signature where it is actually needed(**as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class**)

   Regarding this point, I'm not sure how to implement it. Should I add `@Lazy`? This seems impractical, and I'm not sure if I'm missing any concepts.

Comment: You generally don't have to worry about unexplained downvotes - especially if they are followed by upvotes. People's opinions are their own, a single downvote doesn't mean much.

Comment: No. Self referencing would be if you would inject `Course` as a field into the `JavaConfig` or as a constructor argument. As the configuration class would then needed to be constructed to inject the dependency into itself, effectively adding a dependency on itself through this. Using a bean created through an `@Bean` method is not self referencing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wow, please answer the question instead of comment!! I saw you in the Java top users, can you give me some examples and tell me what I missed? Thank you!!!

Comment: I already wrote an answer... WIth both field and constructor sample.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot!! And, what does "as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class" mean?

Comment: That is what you are doing in your sample. You aren't using an autowired field (as in my answer) but just a method argument in your `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding self-referencing in the case of an `@Configuration` class. Self referencing is when you would inject the `Course` as a field (or constructor argument into the `JavaConfig`.

```java
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

 @Autowired
 private Course course;  

 @Bean
 Course course() {
   return new Course();
 }
}
```

Now the `JavaConfig` has a field of type `Course`. Which is constructed by the same `JavaConfig` class. To inject the `course` field it would need to do `new JavaConfig().course()` but the call to `course()` can only done if all dependencies have been injected. Hence the `JavaConfig` effectively has a dependency on itself.

With a constructor it would be more visible

```java
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

 private Course course;  

 public JavaConfig(Course course) {
   this.course=course;
 }

 @Bean
 Course course() {
   return new Course();
 }
}
```

Spring needs to be able to call the `course()` method to fulfill the constuctor argument, but to do so it needs to construct a `JavaConfig` which is now impossible.

Marking the field/argument with `@Lazy` will circumvent this as it will delay the injection of the actual `Course` until it is actually needed (i.e. methods are called on it). Until then it will inject a proxy for the `Course` object.

Making the `course()` bean method `static` will also solve it as you don't need an instance of `JavaConfig` to call the `course()` method because of the `static` nature.

Answer (score -1):

> Self-referencing refers to the situation where Bean A calls Bean B within the same configuration class, or when other Beans are used as parameters, right?

Self referencing means that you use the bean as an dependency in the class itself, demonstrated on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-self-injection):

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean self;

    public void doSomething() {
        // use self reference here
    }
}
```

However, the snipped you provided in the question talks about Bean methods. These methods provide Beans to the system. Consuming such a Bean in the same class is similar to a self reference, not 100% the same but you run into the same issue: circular dependencies.

> Regarding this point, I'm not sure how to implement it. Should I add @Lazy? This seems impractical, and I'm not sure if I'm missing any concepts.

To resolve circular dependencies you could add @Lazy, this can work but I would not recommend it as startup problems effectively turn into runtime problems if something goes the wrong way. You could move the consuming beans into their own configuration class, thus splitting providers and consumers into two classes which removes the circular dependency.

Comment: So, what I expressed is probably correct? I understand that what you said may not be exactly the same 100%, but for example, the `this` keyword itself is a self-reference, and it is similar to what is described in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, the general thought is correct, I was just nitpicking.

Comment: I still don't quite understand this sentence: "Either lazily resolve such references in the method signature where it is actually needed (as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class)." What is this sentence trying to convey?

Comment: No you are wrong. This isn't self referencing in the sense of an `@Configuration` (hence the downvote on this answer).

Comment: Specifically, "as opposed to an autowired field in the configuration class" means that `@Autowired` and `@Lazy` are in contrast with each other??

Comment: Where am I wrong here specifically? Baeldung as a source is credible as well as the official documentation linked in the question.